# Ajax showing output as parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have three textareas and I want to alert the text in that textarea using Ajax.

```
function myKeyPress(e, x, y) {
    var AjaxObj = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        AjaxObj = new XMLHttpRequest;
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        AjaxObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (AjaxObj != null) {
        var a = document.getElementById("TSI_Query_Box").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("SI_Query_Box").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("Ship_ID").value;
        var params = "TSI_Query_Box=" + a + "&SI_Query_Box=" + b + "&ShipID=" + c;
    } else {
        alert("No Ajax Found. please update your Browser");
    }
    var keynum;
    if (window.event) {
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    } else if (e.which) {
        keynum = e.which;
    }
    if (keynum == 13) {
        alert(params);
    }
}
```

here the problem is when I take `document.getElementById(//textareaID).value;`, there is nothing happening, and when I take it as `document.getElementById(//textareaID);`, it is giving output as `[Object]`, please let me know how do I get the textbox values in the alert message.

Comment: *"there is nothing happening"* means what exactly? What do you expect to happen? Instead of us guessing what could be wrong, learn how to set breakpoints and debug your code: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Comment: Hi Felis, here actually i'm using a keyevent. i.e. if i hit enter the alert message should come, but no next line. when i use .value, a new line comes in textarea.

Comment: Need more information. Can you please show the html for your text area